# Java - Code executes w/o exception but no print job prints

Tags: java, printing

I have what should be a simple task: print a text file in Java, but although the code execute without error, nothing actually comes out of the printer.  I check the print queues and they're empty.  I'm using Java 8 on Windows 10.

I've tried a lot of code to get things working, but this is what I ended up with.  This may all be a local issue, but maybe someone can spot something in my code that's wrong or fishy.

```
package net.snortum.play;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import javax.print.Doc;
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintException;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.ServiceUI;
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;
import javax.print.attribute.DocAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.HashDocAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaSizeName;

public class PrinterPlay {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PrinterPlay().run();
    }

    private void run() {
        String filename = "src/net/snortum/play/PrinterPlay.java";
        PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
        PrintService printService[] = PrintServiceLookup
                .lookupPrintServices(flavor, pras);

        if (printService == null || printService.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("No printer could be found");
            return;
        }

        try {
            PrintService defaultService = PrintServiceLookup
                    .lookupDefaultPrintService();
            PrintService service = ServiceUI.printDialog(null, 200, 200,
                    printService, defaultService, flavor, pras);

            if (service == null) {
                System.out.println("Printing canceled");
                return;
            }

            System.out.println(service.getName());
            DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            DocAttributeSet das = new HashDocAttributeSet();
            das.add(MediaSizeName.NA_LETTER);
            Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fis, flavor, das);
            job.print(doc, pras);
            System.out.println("Print job sent without exception");

        } catch (PrintException pe) {
            System.out.println("Problem printing");
            pe.printStackTrace();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            System.out.println("Can't find file");
            fnfe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What I've tried and what happened:

- Several different documents and printers: executes without printing
- Printing documents from other programs (like Notepad++): prints
- Change DocFlavor: anything other than AUTOSENSE and I don't get any Printer Services
- Add attributes to PrintRequestAttributeSet: no Printer Services
- Add attributes to DocAttributeSet: executes without printing

Comment: What is the actual output of this?

Comment: For "executes without printing", I get the printer name and then "Print job sent without exception".  If I don't get any print services, the output is "No printer could be found".